# vue.js watch array variable within v-repeat

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to watch a variable within an array that is bound to a repeating element using v-repeat but it doesnt seem to be working. There is a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cookstaar/yryvLw2x/)

My HTML looks something like this

```
<div id="test">
    <div v-repeat="details">
        <select v-model="hour">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <pre>
          {{ $data | json }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

and the vue js like this

```
new Vue({
        el: '#test',
        data: {
            details: [
                { 
                    hour: 2,
                    changeThis: null
                },
                { 
                    hour: 3,
                    changeThis: null
                }
            ],
        },
        watch: {
            'details': function (val, oldVal) {
                alert()
            },
        }
})
```

The binding to the hour properties is working fine, but I cannot get the watch to fire. I have also tried deep: true but that doesnt work either. If I define my watch as

```
watch: {
    'details[0].hour'
```

then I can get it to work, but as I dont know how many details I will have then I dont really want to do this for each one. What I ideally want to do is get a reference to the array item that is being updated and then go from there. I could possibly achieve what I want by adding a

```
v-on="change:someVar(detail)"
```

to the select element and doing it that way but I'm curious as to why the approach I am trying does not work.

**Edit**
It is actually possible to return the full array by using the deep watcher as @kishanterry notes below (thank you for that), I had overlooked this syntax in the docs.. However it still doesn't quite give the solution I was hoping for

```
// deep watcher
    'c': {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) { /* ... */ },
      deep: true
    }
```

Comment: I tried your fiddle with options in the docs: [link](http://vuejs.org/api/options.html#watch) but seems like the _watcher_ returns a **copy** of the variables its _watching_ (not the reference) and even if *deep* option is set to `true`, the whole _watched_ array is passed as **val**. Your best bet is to use `v-on="change: ..."` event listening format

Comment: @kishanterry Thank you for taking a look. I had actually overlooked the syntax for the deepwatcher which may give me some of what I need. But as you say it may be best to fall back to v-on

Comment: what exactly do you want in the watcher callback?

Comment: @EvanYou it maybe that the v-on="change:someVar(detail)" is a better route but I was hoping to somehow get hold of the item in the array that has changed and then change some values in that. For example if 'hour' changes, then I want to do something to the adjacent 'changeThis' property

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off making the repeated item a component!

Comment: @EvanYou, I was trying to avoid the overhead of a component. Seems like the approach I was attempting is not suggested so I will revert to using v-on to pickup the change to the value via the select. That should work. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new Vue({
 el: '#test',
 data: {
  details: [{
    hour: 2,
    changeThis: null
   },
   {
    hour: 3,
    changeThis: null
   }
  ],
 },
 watch: {
  details: {
   handler: function(val, oldVal) {
    alert('')
   },
   deep: true
  }
 }
})
```

It is working if I replace it in your js fiddle.I think it is what you need.
[Js Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wpa1dx23/)